# Merge two time-series in pandas & extract observations within threshold time difference

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two time series in pandas that have observations at seemingly-random times. The code below will create some example time series:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(5), index=['2014-05-06 09:15:34', '2014-05-06 09:34:00',
                                         '2014-05-06 11:20:43', '2014-05-07 12:13:00',
                                         '2014-05-07 17:29:19'])
s1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s1.index)

s2 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(6)*10, index=['2014-05-03 10:20:09', '2014-05-06 09:13:26',
                                            '2014-05-06 09:23:38', '2014-05-06 11:09:52',
                                            '2014-05-07 12:14:08', '2014-05-07 17:35:19'])
s2.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s2.index)
```

Giving `s1`:

```
2014-05-06 09:15:34    0
2014-05-06 09:34:00    1
2014-05-06 11:20:43    2
2014-05-07 12:13:00    3
2014-05-07 17:29:19    4
dtype: int64
```

and `s2`:

```
2014-05-03 10:20:09     0
2014-05-06 09:13:26    10
2014-05-06 09:23:38    20
2014-05-06 11:09:52    30
2014-05-07 12:14:08    40
2014-05-07 17:35:19    50
dtype: int64
```

I want to merge these time series and extract the rows where there are observations in each time series *within 10 minutes of each other*. So, using the data above:

- The first element of `s2` wouldn't match anything at all in `s1`.
- The second element of `s2` is within about 2 minutes of the first element of `s1`, so these would match.
- and so on...

Ideally, I'd end up with a `DataFrame` with columns of `s1_time`, `s1_value`, `s2_time`, `s2_value`, but I'm not really fussed about the exact format of the output.

I've tried loads of different approaches to this, using `pd.merge`, trying to use `asof` and so on - but I've ended up confusing myself entirely. I'm sure this is a problem that has been solved before, but I can't seem to find much online that relates to randomly-spaced time-series (a lot is based on things being hourly or daily).

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 3):

You can first use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with `method='nearest'` and then if values in `s2` are `unique`, [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by this values:

```
print (s2.reindex(s1.index, method='nearest'))
2014-05-06 09:15:34    10
2014-05-06 09:34:00    20
2014-05-06 11:20:43    30
2014-05-07 12:13:00    40
2014-05-07 17:29:19    50
dtype: int32

print (pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1, 's2':s2.reindex(s1.index, method='nearest'), 'index_s1': s1.index}))
                               index_s1  s1  s2
2014-05-06 09:15:34 2014-05-06 09:15:34   0  10
2014-05-06 09:34:00 2014-05-06 09:34:00   1  20
2014-05-06 11:20:43 2014-05-06 11:20:43   2  30
2014-05-07 12:13:00 2014-05-07 12:13:00   3  40
2014-05-07 17:29:19 2014-05-07 17:29:19   4  50

print (pd.merge(s2.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'s2'}),
                pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1, 's2':s2.reindex(s1.index, method='nearest'), 'index_s1': s1.index}),
                on='s2').rename(columns={'index':'index_s2'}))

             index_s2  s2            index_s1  s1
0 2014-05-06 09:13:26  10 2014-05-06 09:15:34   0
1 2014-05-06 09:23:38  20 2014-05-06 09:34:00   1
2 2014-05-06 11:09:52  30 2014-05-06 11:20:43   2
3 2014-05-07 12:14:08  40 2014-05-07 12:13:00   3
4 2014-05-07 17:35:19  50 2014-05-07 17:29:19   4
```

EDIT:

I found new parameter `tolerance` in `reindex`:

```
print (s2.reindex(s1.index, method='nearest',tolerance='10Min'))
2014-05-06 09:15:34    10.0
2014-05-06 09:34:00     NaN
2014-05-06 11:20:43     NaN
2014-05-07 12:13:00    40.0
2014-05-07 17:29:19    50.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know `reindex` could do that. However, is there a way to include a 'time difference threshold' for the `nearest` bit? I want to only match observations that are within 10 minutes of each other - and your example output shows `09:23:38` and 09:34:00` matched, which are more than 10 mins apart.

Comment: Phooo, I think this treshhold can be problem. But maybe you can `resample` data by 10 minutes. Give me a time.

Comment: I try `print (s1.resample('10T').sum())`, but it change only datetimeindex to 10 minutes interval. Unfortunately now I have no other idea. Maybe someone post better answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about a slightly longer solution?

```
import datetime

d = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
ans = [(xi, x, yi, y) for xi, x in zip(s1.index, s1) for yi, y in zip(s2.index, s2) if xi.to_datetime() - d < yi.to_datetime() < xi.to_datetime() + d]
pd.DataFrame(ans, columns=['s1_time', 's1_value', 's2_time', 's2_value'])
```